# Illegal String offset SEO

Tags: php, arrays, string

I read a bit around here, but as I'm a newbie I couldn't configure what to change the description to on my own, can someone help me?

I get this error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'seodescription' in C:\xampp\htdocs\testdb1\wp-content\themes\prospect\functions\meta-box.php on line 37

Line 37 looks something like this:

```
echo htmlspecialchars( $data[ $meta_box[ 'name' ] ] );
```

Is the [] what is going against me? If yes, how do I change them and keep the $meta_box definition?

Comment: The warning is referring to `seodescription`, which the code you included doesn't contain. What's the actual line involved?

Comment: Please write that line in code format.

Comment: the only seodescription is in the beginning of the meta box file on line 7 or smting, not 37?

Comment: <?php
$key = "seostuffkey";
$meta_boxes = array(
"seotitle" => array(
"name" => "seotitle",
"title" => "Page Title",
"description" => "Type your custom page title here. This will overwrite the page title written in your post editor and also for the title in search engines."),
"seodescription" => array(
"name" => "seodescription",
"title" => "Page Description",
"description" => "Type your custom page description here. This will be used for the description in search engines and show below the title.")
);

Comment: Alright, $meta_box[ 'name' ] is not valid but $meta_box['seodescription'][ 'name' ] is valid.

Comment: great ty guys all solved now seems to work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

In the below line:

```
$data[ $meta_box[ 'name' ] ]
```

It looks like `$data` doesn't have a value with the key `$meta_box['name']`. Make sure you have have the right key and also make sure `$data` is defined and accessible.

Replace the above line with the one below.

```
$data[$meta_box['seodescription']['name']];
```

Also what do you get when you print_r($data) ? Add this print statement before line 37. Paste your output.

Comment: That would cause an `undefined index` warning, not an `illegal string index`

Comment: I'm really sorry for the dumb question, but how do I check the value of the key and it being defined? earlier on in the metabox?

Comment: try to echo $meta_box[ 'name' ], tell us what you get and also try to print $data like print_r($data) and tell us what you get.

Comment: do I replace the original code with this or do i write something else separately? if replacing, first one still gives me an error

Comment: You dont have to replace. Write those two statements before line 37 and then write die() to end the script. Print your output here.

Answer (score 0):

$data is not an array (but apparently a string) when the script reaches line 37.
To test that try something like

```
if ( !is_array($data) ) {
    echo '$data is not an array.';
    var_dump($data);
    die;
}
else if ( !isset($data[ $meta_box[ 'name' ] ]) ) {
    echo '$data doesn\'t have a key ', $meta_box[ 'name' ];
    die;
}
else {
    echo htmlspecialchars( $data[ $meta_box[ 'name' ] ] );
}
```